# Entity Framework code first - Array of foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity with a list of other entites. 
The other entities are "read only" and are only a mere association. 
The meaning is that the entity should only have a list of the other entities ids and nothing more. 
How can I achive this so I can have as simple as possible update graph later on?

```
 public class Worker
 {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Age { get; set; }

    public int? ManagerID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManagerID")]
    public virtual Worker Manager { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is just an association to the tasks. 
    /// An update graph should ignore the entity itself since 
    /// the task is immutable in this context!!!
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Task> AssignedTasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string TaskName { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is just an association to the workers. 
    /// An update graph should ignore the entity itself 
    /// since the worker is immutable in this context!!!
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<Worker> AssignedWorkers { get; set; }
}
```

I need just the entities **ids**... BUT the collections are used to build the DB schema...

In the example above - On update the worker just need to update the tasks ids that were assigned to him and not their whole data

Comment: I have added an example and further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the actual list of entities as private virtual. This will prevent outside access. Then create the list of ids as a property that does a `.Select(e => e.Id)` on your entity list. The entity list would only be able to be modified from inside the parent entity.

Comment: It's not an option. The model is used for graph creation. I need the types collection so entity framework would be able to create the relation...

Comment: I guess I'm unclear as to what you exactly need. It seems you need a read only collection of entities and a collection of those entities' ids to be used. Am I correct? How do you plan on updating the graph later?

Comment: I'll explain. When you have a nested object you can create a FK property for it. This property holds the id and id only and if you   want you can skip loading the entire object and just hold the id. It's extremely useful on update scenario where you know you don't need any chnage in that nested object and don't need it's data. But when you have a list of such objects you can't just hold their ids as you did for a single object and this is what I try to find out. In the example above - On update the worker just need to update the  tasks ids that were assigned to him and not their whole data.

Comment: What about using a Data Transfer Object type of abstraction? Make an object that behaves the way you want, and then when you are finished with it, pass it to a repository and line up the data with the entity. It's much cleaner than trying to force EF to do something it really wasn't meant to do.